# Сломанная анимация в SettingsActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

При генерации SettingsActivity было все нормально. В какой-то момент (я ничего, кроме xml файла не менял) произошло урезание длины всех элементов на половину. Выглядит это так:

[image: Изменение длины]

На андроид устройстве выглядит все нормально, но сломалась стандартная анимация нажатия. Перегенерация такого активити не помогла.

Выглядит на устройстве это так:

[image: Анимация]

Привожу код `root_preferences.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:key="main"
    app:iconSpaceReserved="false">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:id="@+id/url"
        android:defaultValue="192.168.31.38"
        android:key="url"
        android:summary="@string/default_url"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
        android:title="Change url"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false" />
    <SwitchPreference
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
        android:id="@+id/sw_use_port"
        android:key="use"
        android:title="Use Port" />
    <EditTextPreference
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
        android:id="@+id/port"
        android:key="port"
        android:dependency="use"
        android:defaultValue="1337"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
        android:title="Port" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Код `SittingsActivity.java`:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle("Settings");
        }

    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

        }
    }
}
```

Код `settings_activity.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Выглядит очень неприятно. Заранее спасибо, если знаете как исправить

Comment: а если попробовать добавить `android:defaultValue="true"` например?

Comment: Не работает, а анимация сломана на всех элементах

Comment: а зачем вы везде установили `app:iconSpaceReserved="false"`?

Comment: Потому что появляется ненужный мне отступ слева.

Comment: я бы попробовал убрать все такие поля у всех элементов и посмотреть изменится ли что-то, и не очень понятно что за отступ)

Comment: Отступы получаются как здесь: https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/issues/1866. И нет, это не помогло

Comment: а иконки добавить я так понимаю не вариант? можно так же заменить все элементы на appCompat... но не уверен что это наверняка поможет :)

Comment: Может, вы помните, что именно было изменено? Попробуйте вернуть старый код и посмотрите, поменялось ли что-нибудь. Заодно можете и вопрос дополнить (старым кодом, если остался)

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу вернуть старый код. Единственное, что я поменял - это xml, больше ничего (Кроме других классов, которые никак не имеют отношение к Settings)